# Windows Media Player buttons appear with broken image link

Tags: windows-8, audio, images, windows-media-player

This issue started today. I opened up Windows Media Player and found that all the icons/buttons for Play, Pause, Stop, etc were shown as broken image files. 
I have followed steps on uninstalling & re-installing Windows Media Player in the Control Panel>Programs&Features tab; unchecking the box, restarting; re-checking the box, and nothing has helped.

The music still plays, but I cannot stop/pause the music, since the buttons are not there. Curiously though, the volume bar still moves up and down, and changes the volume of the audio, but the icons are missing as well. The hot keys also do not work. I have no control over stopping the song once it starts other than to close to program.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNdaY.png)
Has anyone seen this issue before?

Answer (score 0):

If you use System Restore to roll back the system to a point from before the problem started happening, does that help?